# Correctly write my files so they can open as text when my app is not installed

Tags: swift, cocoa, document

My application writes files known as ".nec", which are simply text files. I'd like them to open in my app if it's on the machine, or open in the default text editor if it's not.

There are surprisingly few examples of how to set these things in Apple's documentation. Do I simply set the MIME type to `text/plain`, or are there other things I should do as well?

Answer (score 1):

Most computers / mobile devices will use the file extension to determine the file type rather than read the file headers so if you are using a custom file extension then the device won't know which application handles that file.

If you want your applications documents to opened by something outside of your application you will need to use a standard format for your file type.

For textual documents the most common are likely to be .txt, .rtf and .doc

If your documents are just plain text without any formatting (like a log file) then you would be best using .txt, you shouldn't need to change much (if anything) to write in this format.

After a quick google of the file extension .nec I found this:

> NEC files are Uncommon Files primarily associated with Unknown Apple II File (found on Golden Orchard Apple II CD Rom).
>
> NEC files are also associated with NEC JIS Encoded File, PIMS Notes for Windows CE Audio Record File (Nacetech Co. Ltd.) and FileViewPro.

If one of your files were to be (for example) emailed to a windows user, Windows would not know that this is a simple text file and would likely prompt the user  to search online for a program that handles this file extension.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I know this is not the case. There are many files on the Mac with extensions that are not .txt that you right-click and see that your text editor is the suggested app to open it. There are others where that is not the suggested app to open it. Something triggers this behaviour and I'd like to use it.

Comment: on the mac when you do open with, I believe it will look at the file extension and headers and suggest suitable applications, but not all operating systems, including mobile will. unfortunately, if you want universal support you will need a universal file type

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer as such, but as to date you don't have one here are some things to explore in the hope it is useful.

The old style type *and* creator of Mac OS have just about gone, first to replaced by just file extensions, and now there are UTIs.

If you read Apple's [Uniform Type Identifier Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html) you will see your app can declare a UTI, say `com.markowitz.nectext`, which conforms to the standard UTI `public.text`. Now a UTI helps the Finder (Launch Services) locate the app to open a file, you could explore what happens if there is no such app available but the UTI declares it conforms to `public.text`.

*[Just seen your comment on another answer re: right-clicking. At a guess this would be the UTI above.]*

Another avenue to explore, getting into the undocumented side of OS X, is how the Finder's "Get Info" handles setting the "Open With" preference on a file. Try setting a plain text file to open in your app, then use the `xattr -l <file>` in the Terminal to see what was done. You should see an extended attribute `com.apple.LaunchServices.OpenWith` whose value looks like some form of plist.

Just remember this is undocumented, the API used by the Finder is private, but then its just an extended attribute...

Have fun.